# What is the fastest way to 302 a link to it's final URL?

Tags: java, php, performance, curl, http-status-code-302

given the link http://bit.ly/2994js

What is the most efficient way or library to use that would get you to the final URL of a bit.ly,fb.me, etc... after the 302 redirects? Assume the scale to be 10+ million of these a day with the ability to scale across servers.

Java HttpClient?
PHP with cURL?
other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of bit.ly, there is an API call ([expand](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/expand)) that gets the target URL from the shortened URL. Other URL shortening services may have similar API calls. In those cases, you wouldn't have to handle the redirect.

Comment: The method also supports passing in multiple URLs at once

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that there are limits to this approach (http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#Rate_Limiting)

Comment: gonna give you the vote here because most of the links I'm working with are bit.ly so this was a nice find! Looks like I can call 15 urls at once which is nice.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation language isn't likely to make much odds in terms of performance - there's almost nothing to do. It'll all be network latency. It's possible that using a customized network stack *might* help, but I wouldn't bother unless I really needed to.

I'm not sure whether a 302 response is still able to keep the connection alive with HTTP 1.1 - but if it can, that could really be a boon. That's also an argument *against* using cURL (which is going to start a new process, requiring a new connection) for each URL, unless there's some way of putting cURL into a batch mode. (There may be - worth investigating.)

The important thing will be to make sure that you don't hit any server so hard it thinks you're launching a DDOS attack, but to make as many requests in parallel as you can within that limit.

Note that 10,000,000 per day is only ~116 requests per second. If you've got an adequate network connection and the target servers aren't blocking you, that shouldn't be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

cURL is fastest. So, if you want absolute speed, go with writing a bash script that does it by cURL.

However, making 10+ million request may get your IP banned pretty soon from them.